# Conditionally provide a using declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits, enable-if

Suppose I've got a class `foo` with template parameter `T` and I want to provide a using declaration for the reference and const-reference types corresponding to `T`:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = T const&;
};
```

Is there a way to "enable" these using declerations only if `T` is not `void` **without speclializing the whole class `foo`**?

Comment: You can conditionally derive `foo` from base classes with and without these member types.

Comment: this seems like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve really?

Comment: What your foo is expected to do when T is void and what when T is not void? Write code of usage and what you expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could inherit from a base class with a specialization for `void`:

```
template<typename T>
struct typedefs {
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = T const&;
};

template<>
struct typedefs<void> {};

template<typename T>
struct foo : typedefs<T>
{};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know. I just thought it is somehow strange to have a "traits class" as a base class.

Comment: @0xbadf00d, Nothing wrong with doing that. This is a good answer.

Comment: @0xbadf00d and maybe put `typedefs` into a `detail` namespace to make the intent super clear.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Yes, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want don't want your program to compile with `foo<void>` and don't mind ugly SFINAE, then here is an ugly solution with no specialization:

```cpp
template< typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<void, T>>>
struct foo
{
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = T const&;
};
```